# One of my jQuery scripts just plain isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Hey, I'm having trouble debugging a JQuery script that is suppposed to do something relatively simple: reveal search results of a search plugin after the first search is run. Until then (i.e. on first load of the page), I want the results to be invisible.

The search results are within a div which I'm hiding initally with CSS:

```
#search-filter-results-8513
{
   display: none;
}
```

And here's the contents of my .js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('#search-filter-results-8513').on('sf:ajaxfinish',function(e, x){
   $('#search-filter-results-8513').show();
   console.log(e);
   console.log(x);
});

});
```

It appears to be loading fine, along with two other scripts that I'm adding in functions.php, via WordPress's register-and-enqueue system.

But nothing happens when a search is completed - the results do not show.

I admit I'm not a ground-up JS expert, but I've been able to manage up to now - this has m me stumped though.

I've tried some experiments and it looks like the script never does a thing, regardless of the specific command I try.

Also, despite much Googling I can't get my head around the e and x functions and why they, and the two console.log lines, are needed. But the structure of my .js is exactly as was recommended to me by the theme's developer. He's been helpful but I suspect this is out of his proper area of tech support so I'm throwing the question out to this wider community.

Would love some suggestions and/or links to some good online resources. Thanks!

Comment: Could you give a reference of the "recommended to me by the theme's developer" ? Or what is the theme name... And... What "sf:" stands for? Do you know?

Comment: About e and x... I would say e = event and x = some var, object or array carried by the event. But... On my side, I can't figure out what is `sf:ajaxfinish`. I would need theme name and (if there's an and) plugin name... Any doc link that you have... And eventually: More tryed code. ;)

Comment: In other words... 1 function triggered by unkown event + 1 CSS line and 2 console logs  is... Say thin for anyone to answer.

Comment: I think that **`sf:ajaxfinish`** is related to some ajax **`S`earch  `F`ilter** script or function… Is not possible to help you with the material you are giving on your question. You have to find the other involved functions and then update your question adding the corresponding code…

Comment: A mention of what search plugin you are using and a link would help anyone trying to debug this. Without the documentation for the plugin it is hard to divine how it is supposed to work and why your code isn't.

Comment: My guess is that `'sf:ajaxfinish` is a [custom event](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) that the plugin should be firing when the results have returned. Have you looked in the console to see if the `log` calls are printing anything? Are there any errors in the console? Look at the network panel in your browser's developer tools, was an ajax request actually made? Has it returned?

Comment: Sorry everyone, I did leave out some critical info! "sf:ajaxfinish" is indeed a custom function provided by the plugin, which is Search & Filter Pro. @UselessCode, your guess was spot-on. 

Here's the [page](http://www.designsandcode.com/wordpress-plugins/search-filter-pro/faqs/) on their site that discusses these functions (in the first FAQ question).

There aren't any errors in the console, just CSS warnings. I'll check the other suggestions re the console / dev tools.

Comment: Hi again. Well, turns out that the javascript suggested in their FAQ page differed from that which they provided in their direct-support answer. And, with a little modification, it worked! So it was really about following their  structure. Nothing that could have been sussed out here, I guess! Hey, is it best practice to simply delete my question here, if, as appears to be the case, it doesn't really add anything to the general pool of JS knowledge? Let me know... and thanks to all who chimed in with suggestions!